# Temporarily change a JavaScript global variable

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm trying to invisibly swap one library for another but only for a given scope. Here's a simplified sketch of the problem. `x` represents the old preexisting library, `y` represents the new library and `$` is the global I want to affect. The goal is to have `withLib` successfully change $ from x to y for all the code within it's callback.

You can see with this example, I can affect the code in the outer context but not the inner. I've tried wrapping the `callback()` in a closure but that didn't quite do it either.

```
x = "1.0"
y = "2.0"
$ = x;

withLib = function(callback) {
  $ = y
  callback()
  $ = x
}

withLib(function(){
    console.log($, $ == "2.0" ? "outer success" : 'outer fail')
    someCb = function() {
        console.log($, $=="2.0" ? "inner success" : "inner fail")    
    }
})

someCb() 

// results in "outer success" and "inner fail"
```

I think the answer involves setting up the right kind of closure but I can't see how. Any thoughts?

Comment: What two frameworks? There may be a better solution.

Comment: Library `x` would be an old unknown version of jQuery or similar lib, obtained through `jQuery.noConflict()`, library `y` would be a newly loaded jQuery. I want any code (and any of it's callbacks) wrapped in `withLib` to use the new jQuery. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anonymous function to create a scope where `$` is `y`:

```
x = "1.0"
y = "2.0"
$ = x;

(function ($) {

    console.log($, $ == "2.0" ? "outer success" : 'outer fail')
    someCb = function() {
        console.log($, $=="2.0" ? "inner success" : "inner fail")    
    }

}(y));

someCb()
```

Alternatively, the keyword `with` is generally to be avoided, but if you're set on it:

```
with ({'$': y}) {
    console.log($, $ == "2.0" ? "outer success" : 'outer fail')
    someCb = function() {
        console.log($, $=="2.0" ? "inner success" : "inner fail")    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the function (or functions) that use the old library, you could replace the `$` reference, but only in the local scope like so:

```
function doStuff() {
    var $ = x;
    // do stuff with $
}
```

This will not affect the global values for `$`, `x`, and `y`, but will only work on calls within the scope of `doStuff`.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/rQ54s/

```
x = "1.0"
y = "2.0"

withLib = (function(callback, $) {
  callback($)
})

withLib(function($){
  console.log($, $ == "2.0" ? "outer success" : 'outer fail')
  someCb = function() {
    console.log($, $=="2.0" ? "inner success" : "inner fail")    
  }
}, y)

someCb()
```

Try withLib(..., x) to pass in x as the "$" library.